# when clicked submit get the input values and check the condition and calculate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <p>question 1</p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="A">
      <label>Agree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="N">
      <label>Nuetral</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="D">
      <label>DisAgree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="NA">
      <label>NOt Applicable</label>
    </p>
    <p>question 2</p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="A">
      <label>Agree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="N">
      <label>Nuetral</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="D">
      <label>DisAgree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="NA">
      <label>NOt Applicable</label>
    </p>
    <p>question 3</p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="q3" value="A">
      <label>Agree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q3" value="N">
      <label>Nuetral</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q3" value="D">
      <label>DisAgree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q3" value="NA">
      <label>NOt Applicable</label>
    </p>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var A = 10,
        N = 6,
        D = 3,
        NA = 0;
      var v1, v2, v3;

      $("#submit").click(function() {
        debugger;
        var q1v = $('input[name=q1]:checked').val();
        var q2v = $('input[name=q2]:checked').val();
        var q3v = $('input[name=q3]:checked').val();

        if (v1 == "N") {
          v1 = N;
        } else if (v1 == "A") {
          v1 = A;
        }

        if (v2 == "N") {
          v2 = N;
        } else if (v2 == "A") {
          v2 = A;
        }

        if (v3 == "N") {
          v3 = N;
        } else if (v3 == "A") {
          v3 = A;
        }

        if ((q1v == "A" || q1v == "N") && ((v1 + v2 + v3) / 3 > 0.60)) {
          console("q1 Agree or Nuetral and also value is above 60%");
        } else if ((q2v == "A" || q2v == "N") && ((v1 + v1 + v1 / 3) > 0.60)) {
          console("q2 Agree or Nuetral and also value is above 60% ");
        } else if ((q3v == "A" || q3v == "N") && ((v1 + v1 + v1 / 3) > 0.60)) {
          console("q3 Agree or Nuetral and also value is above 60% ");
        } else {
          console("q1,q2 and q3 DisAgree or NotApplicable and also value is bellow 60% ");
        }
      });

      function toString1(v1, v2, v3) {
        debugger;

        if (v1 == "N") {
          v1 = N;
        } else if (v1 == "A") {
          v1 = A;
        }

        if (v2 == "N") {
          v2 = N;
        } else if (v2 == "A") {
          v2 = A;
        }

        if (v3 == "N") {
          v3 = N;
        } else if (v3 == "A") {
          v3 = A;
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the issue with the code you've dumped in the question?

Comment: if(q1v == "A" || q1v == "N") && ((v1 + v2 + v3) / 3 > 0.60)) here v1, v2, v3 values coming undefine?

Comment: based on condition https://jsfiddle.net/3o6am8f3/5/ console will come but here every time only else block exicuted

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to stop the form submit, because it clear your console.

replace,

```
<form> with   <form onsubmit="return false">
```

2. there is no function called console(), you have to replace console into console.log();

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var A = 10,
        N = 6,
        D = 3,
        NA = 0;
      var v1, v2, v3;

      $("#submit").click(function() {
        debugger;
        var q1v = $('input[name=q1]:checked').val();
        var q2v = $('input[name=q2]:checked').val();
        var q3v = $('input[name=q3]:checked').val();

        if (v1 == "N") {
          v1 = N;
        } else if (v1 == "A") {
          v1 = A;
        }

        if (v2 == "N") {
          v2 = N;
        } else if (v2 == "A") {
          v2 = A;
        }

        if (v3 == "N") {
          v3 = N;
        } else if (v3 == "A") {
          v3 = A;
        }

        if ((q1v == "A" || q1v == "N") && ((v1 + v2 + v3) / 3 > 0.60)) {
          console.log("q1 Agree or Nuetral and also value is above 60%");
        } else if ((q2v == "A" || q2v == "N") && ((v1 + v1 + v1 / 3) > 0.60)) {
          console.log("q2 Agree or Nuetral and also value is above 60% ");
        } else if ((q3v == "A" || q3v == "N") && ((v1 + v1 + v1 / 3) > 0.60)) {
          console.log("q3 Agree or Nuetral and also value is above 60% ");
        } else {
          console.log("q1,q2 and q3 DisAgree or NotApplicable and also value is bellow 60% ");
        }
      });

      function toString1(v1, v2, v3) {
        debugger;

        if (v1 == "N") {
          v1 = N;
        } else if (v1 == "A") {
          v1 = A;
        }

        if (v2 == "N") {
          v2 = N;
        } else if (v2 == "A") {
          v2 = A;
        }

        if (v3 == "N") {
          v3 = N;
        } else if (v3 == "A") {
          v3 = A;
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return false">
    <p>question 1</p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="A">
      <label>Agree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="N">
      <label>Nuetral</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="D">
      <label>DisAgree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="NA">
      <label>NOt Applicable</label>
    </p>
    <p>question 2</p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="A">
      <label>Agree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="N">
      <label>Nuetral</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="D">
      <label>DisAgree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="NA">
      <label>NOt Applicable</label>
    </p>
    <p>question 3</p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="q3" value="A">
      <label>Agree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q3" value="N">
      <label>Nuetral</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q3" value="D">
      <label>DisAgree</label>
      <input type="radio" name="q3" value="NA">
      <label>NOt Applicable</label>
    </p>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: if i  selected agree or Nuetral  first condition need to be excutate but every time else block is excuted please help me

Comment: here v1 and v2 and v3 coming undifined values why?

Comment: you are not assigning v1, v2 & v3 before the condition. what values should go there ?

Comment: Issue is your not assigning values to the radio value(eg. not assigning value 10 for "A" ) so try to put numeric values to the radio buttons

Comment: toString function contain vlaue of v1 and v2  and also v3 but on submit it not coming

Comment: you are not calling toString() function. So call it using proper values.

Comment: see here if quation1 checked radio button disagree means first condition is not exucted then it coming second condition here also radio button select disagree means then it is goes to third condition if third condtion is goes to